# Tailwind PhotoGallery Images are arranging in vertical manner rather then horizontal

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-blade, tailwind-css

**blade file**

```
<div class="containerr  lg:px-32 px-4 py-8 mx-auto items-center  justify-center ">
 
    <div class="w-full max-h-5xl p-5 pb-10 mx-auto mb-10 gap-2  columns-3  space-y-2 items-center">   
      @foreach($collection as  $images) 
         <img height="360" src="{{asset('storage/images/'.$b.'/'.$images->image_name)}}" alt="" srcset="" draggable="false" class="rounded-md h-md">
      @endforeach
    </div>
    
</div>
```

( https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcntc.png)

**this is laravel controller function.**

```
 function albumDetails($id){
       
         $user = Auth::id(); 
        $a = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from albums where album_id = '$id' and created_by = $user"));
        $b= $id; 
        $collection=imageData::select('image_name')->where('album_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
        Session::put('hasAccesskeyowner', 'true');

        return view('albumDetail', compact('a','b','collection'));
         
    }
```

**the images are loading like this**
[↓ ↓ ↓
↓ ↓ ↓
↓ ↓
↓ ↓](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z1Yb.png)

but i wanted to arrange like this

[→ → →
→ → →
→ → →
→](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt2Rb.png)

[enter image description here][3]

[3]:

Comment: Can you show the actual output, and your depicted desired output

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcntc.png like this.

Comment: I recommend you put a play tailwind sample with some of the images there, it will be easier to see the problem rather than on a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `columns-3` class, you are getting images in column wise order.

Remove the class `columns-3` and add  `grid grid-rows-3 grid-cols-3` class to order it row wise.

[image]

Attaching the above tailwind example for you which is based on your shared code .

You can see [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/pE6Qp6w2Qa)